# ASP.NET Core model binding behaviour switch

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.2, .net-core-2.2

During some heavy refactorings of an API it seems I changed something effecting the model binding / model validation behaviour.

I tried to investigate the changes I can't figure out what the change caused.

I have a `MyApiController` inheriting from `ControllerBase`. `MyApiController` has a post method receiving a request model (created with the default API template without HTTPS giving you the typical ValuesController).

```
  using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
  using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
  using Newtonsoft.Json;
  using System;
  using System.Threading.Tasks;

  namespace XperimentModelBinding.Controllers
  {

    [ApiController]
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class MyApiController : ControllerBase
    {

      public ILogger<MyApiController> Logger { get; }

      public MyApiController(ILogger<MyApiController> logger)
      {
        Logger = logger ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(logger));
      }


      [HttpPost()]
      public async Task<IActionResult> PostModel([FromBody] MyCreateRequestModel request)
      {

        Logger.LogInformation("PostModel: " + JsonConvert.SerializeObject(request, Formatting.None));

        if (!ModelState.IsValid) return BadRequest(ModelState);

        return Ok();

      }
    }
  }
```

The model I use is:

```
  using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

  namespace XperimentModelBinding
  {

    public class MyCreateRequestModel
    {

      [Required]
      [StringLength(10)]
      public string Name { get; set; }

      [Required]
      [Range(1, 5)]
      public int Value { get; set; }

    }

  }
```

Starting it up and setting a breakpoint at the logger.

Testing with postman:

Test 1:

```
  {
    "Name": "1234567890",
    "Value": 1
  }
```

Breakpoint gets hit, returns 200 OK (as expected).

Test 2:

```
  {
    "Name": null,
    "Value": 1
  }
```

breakpoint doesn't get hit and the returned model is:

```
  {
    "errors": {
        "Name": [
            "The Name field is required."
        ]
    },
    "title": "One or more validation errors occurred.",
    "status": 400,
    "traceId": "80000006-0000-ff00-b63f-84710c7967bb"
  }
```

---

The expected result would be that the method is called, the linebreak is hit and so far I had the response model (seems only containing the errors):

```
{
    "Name": [
        "The Name field is required."
    ]
}
```

---

What changed is: given a request with an invalid model my method got called and I checked with `ModelState.IsValid` if there were errors. That was great because I created my custom response model in that way.

Now my method doesn't get called anymore and the model binding returns directly its own model.

What changed that my method isn't called anymore?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its connected to [ApiController] attribute from [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-2.2)

> Web API controllers don't have to check ModelState.IsValid if they have the > [ApiController] attribute. In that case, an automatic HTTP 400 response containing issue details is returned when model state is invalid. For more information, see Automatic HTTP 400 responses.

Comment: It indeed was the ApiController attribute I added.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use `ConfigureApiBehaviorOptions` inside your `services.AddMvc()` in `Startup.cs` to setup a custom error message to an invalid model request.

```
services.AddMvc()
    .ConfigureApiBehaviorOptions(options => {
        options.InvalidModelStateResponseFactory = actionContext =>
        {
            var modelState = actionContext.ModelState.Values;
            return new BadRequestObjectResult(new ErrorResult(modelState));
        };
    });
});
```

And define your `ErrorResult` class as you want, for example:

```
public class ErrorResult
{
    public int code { get; set; }
    public string message { get; set; }

    public ErrorResult()
    {
    }

    public ErrorResult(ModelStateDictionary.ValueEnumerable modelState)
    {
        // This will take the error message coming directly from modelState
        foreach (var value in modelState)
        {
            if (value.Errors.Count > 0)
            {
                code = 900; // Or use a code handler or whatever
                message = value.Errors.FirstOrDefault().ErrorMessage;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: would that setup also allow/privide a way for centralized logging of bad requests?

Comment: You can add logging inside your custom class. Whenever the constructor is called it means a bad request occurred, you can log it with the whole `modelState` wherever you want.